# Create MySql grants with password using SaltStack

Tags: mysql, salt-stack

To create grants for the database I use the following salt module

```
keystone_grants:
mysql_grants.present:
  - database: keystone.*
  - grant: ALL PRIVILEGES
  - user: keystone
  - host: localhost
```

But it creates me this

```
 ID: Keystone_database
 Function: mysql_grants.present
 Result: True
 Comment: Grant ALL PRIVILEGES on keystone.* to keystone@localhost has been added
Started: 19:42:18.428882
Duration: 4.089 ms
Changes:
```

i.e it creates me this grant

**Grant ALL PRIVILEGES on keystone.* to keystone@localhost**

But I need to create this grant

**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';**

Can someone suggest me how to add grants with password using SaltStack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This state is not able to set password for the permission from the specified host. See salt.states.mysql_user for further instructions.

This sentence is written in the docs of the [salt.modules.mysql_grants](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.mysql_grants.html). They point from there to [salt.states.mysql_user](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.mysql_user.html#module-salt.states.mysql_user). Sadly this docs do not tell a lot on grants.

> This state is not able to grant permissions for the user. See salt.states.mysql_grants for further instructions.

Maybe it is enought to just use both:

```
keystone_grants:
  mysql_grants.present:
    - host: localhost
    - database: keystone.*
    - grant: ALL PRIVILEGES
    - user: keystone
    - host: localhost

keystone:
  mysql_user.present:
    - host: localhost
    - password: somesecret
```

Additionally I would recommend the [mysql-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/mysql-formula).

Comment: It would be quite nice to find some explanation on why both the state and the formula exist.  Niether's documentaton refers to the other, which leads to some confusion on which is intended and if either is meant to supersede the other.

Comment: Well formulas versus states is tricky especially when there are build in states to manage the same service a formula was made for. When you write a formula you usually abstract from what you need to configure regarding your service into one pillar configuration structure. A formula might configure several different pieces related to different software through one interface. States on the other hand aim to solve just one problem by configuring one thing. You can reuse them in your formulas as those are just template based combinations of states. Think of formulas as enhanced states.

Comment: Regarding mysql I'd say that, if you want to manage a mysql server used by several users, and you need to ensure that there are several database with proper permissions you might want to use the formula. If you just setup a service that requires a local mysql database with one user states might be sufficient. Which one to pick depends on you use case and preferences.